# Replace <br> tags in string with line breaks JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, replace, line-breaks

I am using react and pulling from an api where comments are held. There are multiple comments with `br` tags because the api come from a php user. I am trying to replace the `br` tags in each string with an actual line break. I am also using react, so jQuery is a no-go.

This is what I have:

```
this.state.notes.forEach((note) => {
  const fixed = note.body.replace(/<br>/g, "\r\n");
  rows.push(<ListGroupItem hover href="#" className="whiter" key= 
  {note.id}>
    <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <h5 className="mb-1">{ note.name }</h5>
      <small>{ commentDate }</small>
    </div> 
    <p className="mb-1">{ fixed }</p>
  </ListGroupItem>)
}
```

I have replaced it with spaces and it worked, but it hasn't worked with the line break. Where am I going wrong?

Edit 1: @T.J. Crowder I added how it's displayed on the page. `rows` is an empty array and the `ListGroupItem`'s come from MDBootstrap.

Comment: *"I have replaced it with spaces and it worked, but it hasn't worked with the line break."* How are you rendering the string once you've modified it?

Comment: You can try with this text.split( "<br>" ).join( "\n" )

Comment: Fundamentally, if you want the *text* of the comments rather than HTML for the comments, you need to get the other end to send you the text rather than HTML for the text. By sending you HTML, they're giving you a **significant** amount of work to do. You don't want to *just* replace `<br>` with line breaks, because apparently what you're receiving is HTML, and so may have other aspects of HTML you need to deal with, such as named character entities (`&lt;`, `&amp;`, etc.) or numeric character entities (such as `&#003c;`). You have to worry about XSS and various other issues.

Comment: @HemadriDasari - The OP's **already** got valid code replacing `<br>` with line breaks. It's not useful to point them at a *different* way. :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not sending me HTML, just strings. The strings contain `br` tags that end up showing up in the string. I just want to remove the tags from the string and make them actual line breaks because it doesn't look good how they are separated with just spaces.

Comment: @NathanGeckle - Strings with things like `<br>` in them = HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're replacing `<br>` is fine, other than you might want to allow for spaces before the closing `>`, and an optional `/` just before the `>` as well:

```
const fixed = note.body.replace(/<br\s*\\?>/g, "\r\n");
```

But that doesn't solve the problem that what you're getting is HTML, not plain text. You're best off getting the other end to send you the text rather than HTML. By sending you HTML, they're giving you a **significant** amount of work to do. You don't want to *just* replace `<br>` with line breaks, because HTML can have all sorts of other things in it, such as named character entities (`&lt;`, `&amp;`, etc.), numeric character entities (such as `&#003c;`), `script` tags (opening the possibility of XSS attacks), etc. React is smart when you output text and escapes `<` and `&` and such to that they're output as those characters, not HTML, so if the HTML you receive has, say, `&lt;` in it, you'll actually see `&`, `l`, `t`, and `;` in the display, which isn't idea. If your starting point is HTML, interpreting it correctly without allowing scripts and such is difficult. (React does have an option for injecting raw HTML, but it's got an absurdly-awkward name *for a reason*. :-) )

Once you have the text, with standard line breaks (`\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n`), you can render each line in its own `div` to get line breaks in the output, since normally in HTML a line break (or any run of whitespace) is just a single space:

```
<p className="mb-1">{
    fixed.split(/[\r\n]+/).map(line => <div>{line}</div>)
}</p>
```

Example:

```js
const Example = ({fixed}) => {
    return <p className="mb-1">{
        fixed.split(/[\r\n]+/).map(line => <div>{line}</div>)
    }</p>;
};

const str =
  "This is a string with line breaks.\r\n" +
  "Line 2\r\n" +
  "Line 3";
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example fixed={str} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see how this would work, but when I `.replace(/<br\s*\\?>/g, "\r\n")` it doesn't show the "`\r\n`" in the text. It shows the text as if I were replacing it with spaces. Edit: Never mind I failed to call it after the split, so it was still showing the original fixed variable. Thank you for your help!